# Does python move buffers from one logical memory location to another?

Tags: python

In simple python CLI script, I created a memory buffer with Byteio and wrote some data there. I call it from the terminal.

Let's say my program is in progress for one hour.

*Can python interpreter implicitly move my buffer from one logical memory location to another during program execution?*

Comment: This should not affect your directly, because I think that would be an implementation detail or even an OS decision, not something you as a programmer should need to worry about. Is it just curiosty on your part or are you having some issues with it?

Comment: I'm just awfully curious :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. CPython's garbage collector doesn't do moving or compacting. The reason for that is that it provided direct references to objects to C extensions in the early versions (before 2.0), and move to indirect references or read barriers would break C extension compatibility.

PyPy has a more efficient and advanced moving GC, since it doesn't maintain compatibility with C extensions.